# How does get_in() work when you pass it a function?

Tags: elixir

In "Programming Elixir 1.6", there is this example:

```
authors = [
  %{name: "José", language: "Elixir"},
  %{name: "Matz", language: "Ruby"},
  %{name: "Larry", language: "Perl"}
]

languages_with_an_r = fn (:get, collection, next_fn) ->
  for row <- collection do
    if String.contains?(row.language, "r") do
      next_fn.(row)
    end
  end
end

IO.inspect get_in(authors, [languages_with_an_r, :name])
#=> ["José", nil, "Larry"]
```

I have some questions about the example:

1. The function that you pass to `get_in()` is called by Elixir and the first argument that Elixir passes to the function is the atom `:get`.  How is that useful?
2. The third argument that Elixir passes to the function is a function that gets bound to `next_fn`.  Where in the docs does it say how many arguments that function takes? What does that function do? How are we supposed to use `next_fn`? It seems to me that the `for` construct is already iterating over each map in the list, so what does the name `next_fn` even mean?  Is `next_fn` used to somehow tag a row for further consideration?
3. Where does nil in the result list come from?

And, I'll say this: that example is one of the poorest examples I've seen in any programming book--because there's not adequate discussion of the example, and the docs for `get_in()` suck.  That means there are at least three people who don't understand `get_in()`: me, Dave Thomas, and whoever wrote the docs--because if you can't explain something, then you don't understand it yourself.

Edit: I found this in the [source code](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/9196078b5cbcaac6d3649ee7d68a2007d6376786/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L2177):

```
def get_in(data, [h | t]) when is_function(h), 
  do: h.(:get, data, &get_in(&1, t))
```

What does `&1` refer to there?  `data`?  Why not just use `data`, then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I've been playing around in iex a bit:

```
iex(13)> mymax = fn x -> &max(&1, x) end
#Function<6.99386804/1 in :erl_eval.expr/5>

iex(15)> max_versus_3 = mymax.(3)
#Function<6.99386804/1 in :erl_eval.expr/5>

iex(16)> max_versus_3.(4)
4

iex(17)> max_versus_3.(2)
3
```

It looks like the syntax `&max(&1, 3)` returns the anonymous function:

```
fn (arg) -> max(&1, 3)
```

and when x=3 in the surrounding scope, the syntax `&max(&1, x)` will also return the function:

```
fn (arg) -> max(&1, 3)
```

and `&1` will become whatever single arg that the anonymous function is called with.

In this example:

```
authors = [
  %{name: "José", language: "Elixir"},
  %{name: "Matz", language: "Ruby"},
  %{name: "Larry", language: "Perl"}
]

languages_with_an_r = fn (:get, collection, next_fn) ->
  for row <- collection do
    if String.contains?(row.language, "r") do
      next_fn.(row)
    end
  end
end

IO.inspect get_in(authors, [languages_with_an_r, :name])
#=> ["José", nil, "Larry"]
```

The call to `get_in()` here:

```
IO.inspect get_in(authors, [languages_with_an_r, :name])
```

matches the following function definition in the source code:

```
def get_in(data, [h | t]) when is_function(h), 
    do: h.(:get, data, &get_in(&1, t))
```

which creates the following bindings:

```
data = authors
h = languages_with_an_r
t = [:name]
```

Then Elixir executes the body of the function and calls:

```
h.(:get, data, &get_in(&1, t))
```

which is equivalent to:

```
languages_with_an_r.(
     :get, 
     authors, 
     fn (arg) -> get_in(&1, [:name])
```

That creates the binding:

```
next_fn = fn (arg) -> get_in(&1, [:name])
```

Therefore, in the authors example the line:

```
next_fn.(row)
```

is equivalent to calling:

```
fn (row) -> get_in(&1, [:name])
```

which causes `get_in()` to execute with these arguments:

```
get_in(row, [:name])
```

and that call to `get_in()` returns the value corresponding to the `:name` key in `row`.  I think the authors example would be clearer if the parameter variables in the definition of `languages_with_an_r()` were renamed:

```
languages_with_an_r = fn (:get, collection, search_for_next_key_in) ->
      for row <- collection do
        if String.contains?(row.language, "r") do
          search_for_next_key_in.(row)
        end
      end
    end
```

That code will only search for the `:name` key in `row` if `row.language` contains an "r".

Finally, the following snippet shows where `nil` comes from:

```
iex(5)> for x <- [1, 2, 3] do       
...(5)> if x == 1_000_000, do: x+1    
...(5)> end
[nil, nil, nil]
```

Like in Ruby, it appears that a `do block` in Elixir returns the value of the last expression that was evaluated.  And, when a `do block` doesn't evaluate an expression, then the `do block` returns `nil` by default.  Therefore, if `row.language` does not contain an "r", then the if statement is skipped, and the `do block` doesn't evaluate any expressions, so by default the `do block` returns nil.

Comment: that was an excellent analysis of that function that i'm reading about in the book. If you write a book on Elixir, or any other language let me know. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I also stuck at the same part of the bool.